# Android Backpress

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen

I have 5 activities in my android app.
Activity A = Splash
Activity B and Activity C = taking some user data
Activity D and Activity E are showing some calculated values based on user information given in Activity B and C.
Activity B and C will not appear again to user after first time he launch my app. so user is able to insert his info only once. (This i have done using shared preference)
Now What i Want is, if user press back button from Activity D and E , again whenever he start the app Splash screen appear and take him directly to Activity D and E. Never on Activity B and D.

I am doing this in code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Do you want to exit");
    // alert.setMessage("Message");

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Your action here
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            onDestroy();

            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {}
    });

    alert.show();

}
```

So this code works but when I start my app again Splash screen appears = Activity A and after that it redirect my to Activity B and Activity C then.

Also I have passed intent in Splash activity to Activity B that work here. I do not want this. Kindly guide me.

Comment: You mean never to activity B and C at the end of your question?

Comment: Yes #Darpan I dont want users to re-enter there data again that my Activity B and Activity C is asking form user.

Comment: then @mysticmagic 's answer will work I guess. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity A, (Splash screen) check if this is first run or not and redirect user accordingly:

First time, when user saves data in Activity B and C, save an extra boolean along with your user information:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
editor.commit();
```

Change the code where you start Activity B, like this:

```
SharedPreferences shared_prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE); 
boolean firstRun= shared_prefs.getBoolean("firstRun", true);
if(firstRun)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
else
{
    Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityD.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I will try doing this. Thanks

Comment: MysticMagic kindly tell me how can I give this shared preference code on public void onBackPressed() {}

Comment: What's issue in that?

Comment: I gave this code that u wrote here on backpress in Splash screen that is my Activity A. when I press back. on restart of my app Splash screen appears and taking me to Activity B. :(

Comment: editor.put code will go in onSubmit of Activity D and E

Comment: You mean onSubmit of Activity B and Activity C? because this is the place where I pass intent to go on next activity.

Comment: But What about my last activity. Activity 5. from where i want to give an exit button only and user can back press. this activity is final. so it wont pass intent to any other activity.

Comment: First time, when your app runs, Activity B and C will save the boolean firstRun as false. So no matter what you do in onBackPressed of Activity 5, but next time, when app will start, it will get the boolean as false, and so B or C won't be started, getting?

Comment: Should I give this first run boolean false in onCreate because in Onsubmit button its not working. I tried. So I will give intent in shared preference on back press at the start of activity and making boolean false in oncreate method? is this what u mean?

Comment: No. That will be wrong, if user presses back without submitting info.

Comment: Yes so what should I do? I am confused.

Comment: Modify Boolean when user submits data. THAT MUST WORK.